# Посимвольное чтение из бинарного файла

Tags: c, файлы

```
/****************************************************************************
Дан бинарный файл, содержащий символы (тип char). 
Удалить из файла все цифры, если они следуют после знаков препинания.
*****************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 0;
    char a[1000], ch[1000];
    FILE* file = fopen("1.bin", "wb");
    printf("\nput string into the file '1.bin'\n");
    gets(ch);
    fwrite(&ch, sizeof(1000), 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    FILE* read = fopen("1.bin", "rb");

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ch); i++)
    {
        fread(&a[i], sizeof(char), 1, read);

        if (isdigit(a[i]))
        {
            printf("true");
        }

        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }

    fclose(read);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

В бинарный файл записываем строку, нужно вывести ее посимвольно. Проблема в том, что данный код выводит только первых 4 символа и я не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(strlen(ch))` - это размер возвращаемого значения `strlen(ch)`, т.е. размер целочисленного значения - в вашем случае ровно 4 байта...

Так же, как и `sizeof(1000)` равно 4. Вы записываете в файл **только 4 байта**...

Как вы их потом читаете (вернее, пытаетесь) - по 4 байта - это уже другой, но тоже очень болезненный вопрос :)

Comment: Да, понял. Строку в файл записывать нужно через fputs, а не через fwrite. fputs(ch,file); <- для моего кода

Comment: Можно как угодно. Лишь бы запись и чтение работали согласованно.

Comment: "Размер `int`"? Вообще-то `strlen` возвращает `size_t`, а не `int`. Соответственно `sizeof(strlen(ch))` - это размер `size_t`. На "привычных" платформах - 4 или 8.

Comment: @AnT Это, конечно, принципиально меняет дело.

Comment: @Harry; Да, и еще как! Я бы не стал делать это замечание, если бы оно не было исключительно важным.